# How Can I Force Sending an UDP Packet trough an interface?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp

Some context information :

I am implementing Ethernet communication with an FPGA. The FPGA doesn't implement ARP and other protocol like icmp for ping, it just send and receive UDP packet. Trying to implement Ethernet receiving functionality on the FPGA, I am writing a program in C# to send a packet, then read the answer from FPGA (the FPGA should send the same packet, if my receive functionality work on it). It is a point to point connection, no switch or router between FPGA and computer.

Now the problem :
If I try to send to normal network(the one with other computer, 200.200.200.x), existing or not IP, everything is fine, wireshark show the packet has been sent. However, If I try to send to the network with my FPGA, 192.168.25.x(192.168.25.25 is the FPGA) I see no packet sent into wireshark.

What I did :

- I added a static arp entry for the FPGA:

  ```
    arp -s 192.168.25.25 00-00-DE-AD-BE-EF
  ```
- I added a static arp entry for the FPGA.
- Tried to add a static route, then removing it, well, played a lot with route (by the way, my PC network interface is 192.168.25.10) :

  ```
  route add 192.168.25.25 192.168.25.10
  ```
- Set windows firewall to allow UDP traffic on this application

Now the program, in C# (with the windows form GUI removed to don't bloat the post, I just keep the network detail. Anyway, we know the program work in general, we are just debugging out network):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


Socket udpSocket;    
udpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
udpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontRoute, true);
ipDestinationEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.25.25"), 4096);
ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.25.10"), 4096);
udpSocket.Bind(ipLocalEndPoint);
udpSocket.SendTo(data, ipDestinationEndPoint);// (data is a byte array defined earlier)
```

Edit:
When I check windows adapter statistic, it show some packet has been sent, netstat also show it, that packet was sent trough the right interface. But wireshark show nothing, and when I hook up an oscilloscope's probe to the receive line on my phy (FPGA side) I see nothing.

Comment: I think this question could fit to SuperUser. Btw: Is Wireshark listening on the correct interface?

Comment: Yes, and why super user?

Comment: Because your code seems fine, your `route` use not, and other things like firewall configuration, Wireshark use etc. are off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Clijsters why SuperUser and not ServerFault? SuperUser is for general issues, ServerFault is for network administration.

Comment: Server fault could also fit. The question is more about 'general computing' I think. Either way Not StackOverflow